# How does c++ think when accessing a function with arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, output

Im confused as to how c++ reads the following, im not understanding how it access the function and how it outputs 4 3 2 1 0;

```
int q1 (int x[], int &y, int z){ 
    for (int i = z; i >= 0; i--){ 
        x[i] = y++;   

    } 
    z += 1; 
    return z - 2;    

} 

int main (void) {

int b = 0, c = 4, d; 
int a[5] = {0}; 
d = q1(a, b, c); 

for (int i = 0; i <= c; i++){ 
    cout <<  a[i] << " "; 
} 
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Me too.  This is very existential.  I'm not sure what C++ "thinks" about an empty line.

Comment: It probably thinks "unexpected end of file"

Comment: So what do you not understand?

Comment: i wouldve thought the output would be 0 0 0 0 0, because a[5] ={0}

Comment: hey guys, I dont think donwvoting will sove problems. Just tell him what to do or where to find this solution might be more helpful. Just speak for myself :)

Comment: @gongzhitaao: There was no code in the question for the first few minutes, it was edited in later.  That's why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `int q1 (int x[], int &y, int z)`. You pass `a`(pointer to the beginning of the array) to `q1`, so `x` is `a` in function `q1`. In this sense, changing `x` is changing `a`.
2. `y++`. Every iteration, `y` gets `1` more. So?

Comment: ok so in the main, it would first go a[0] then print, a[1] then print, a[2] then print... where is it getting the number 4 for a[0], 3 for a[1] and so on...

Comment: do you notice this ``d = q1(a, b, c); ``?? Call to ``q1``? Just below the ``int a[5] = {0};``.

Comment: yes i get that , i get a is x in the function, i just dont get how its printing

Comment: @ACizzle as I've said, in function `q1`, you've already changed the content of `a[0], a[1], ..., a[4]`, So it's printing the new content!

Comment: ok so it would go a[4] = 1
a[3] = 2
a[2] = 3
a[1] = 4
a[0] = 5

Comment: Yes and no. because it's ``x[i] = y++;`` which means *use ``y`` first and then increment it``*. So `a[0] = 4` and so forth.

Comment: ok then the new value would be 'a[5] = {4,3,2,1,0}' and thats what its accessing then printing?

Comment: @ACizzle Glad to help. An introduction to Cpp might be of some help. This is basic cpp question, like [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).